# Could not locate clojure/tools/logging__init.class

Tags: clojure

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/tools/logging__init.class or clojure/tools/logging.clj on classpath**

Getting this error every time I run the project using.

There is a stack trace but it doesn't show whether the error is coming from my code or not ?

```
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
at tombooth.friend_token$eval3554$loading__4910__auto____3555.invoke(friend_token.clj:1)
at tombooth.friend_token$eval3554.invoke(friend_token.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at auth_friend.handler$eval1857$loading__4910__auto____1858.invoke(handler.clj:1)
at auth_friend.handler$eval1857.invoke(handler.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
```

I was running the basic sample for this friend-redis-token [project](https://github.com/tombooth/friend-token-redis)
Also I am running `Leiningen 2.3.3 on Java 1.7.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

**EDIT: Here is the project.clj**

```
(defproject auth_friend "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  :description "FIXME: write description"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                 [com.cemerick/friend "0.2.0"]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 



  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.8"]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  :ring {:handler auth_friend.handler/app}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  :profiles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

initially I tried by mentioning the clojar as a dependency as given in the github page of the project and then later on I downloaded both the repositories and made them part of my project.
keeping the namespace same.
but still its giving exactly the same issue.

```
.
├── #auth_fri#
├── README.md
├── project.clj
├── resources
│   └── public
├── src
│   ├── auth_friend
│   │   ├── #handler.clj#
│   │   └── handler.clj
│   └── tombooth
│       ├── friend_token
│       │   ├── redis.clj
│       │   ├── token.clj
│       │   └── token_store.clj
│       └── friend_token.clj
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   └── stale
│       └── extract-native.dependencies
└── test
    └── auth_friend
        └── test
            └── handler.clj
```

Comment: Please post your project.clj and how do use/require the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging) you need the dependency:

```
  [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.2.6"]
```

In your project, which is missing from the dependency vector on your project file.